# How to un-load codeigniter views

Tags: php, codeigniter

In a relatively heavy function that I want to keep in the same function.

Basically before a `$_POST` function I have the view loaded. and after the function I have a different view.

However the same view as before is also showing, only pushed down below the new view, even though I am simply calling the one view.

Is there something like `$this->unload->view`?

Comment: Why do you load the view before you know that you need the view? Determine first which view to load and load the view afterwards.

Comment: What do you call a `$_POST function`?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `unload` method in CodeIgniter.

You should consider rewriting your code as it's not correct in any way if you want that functionality. The loaded views are passed to the output almost immediately. The only thing you can do is return the view to some variable for later use:

```
$stored_view = $this->load->view('my_view', $data, true);
```

then you can use it in conditionals.

In any case, I am completely sure you are doing something wrong here. Post more description of what you are trying to achieve and the related code so that community could help you.

Answer (score 0):

No need:it's simple

```
if($_POST)
    $this->load->view('view1');
else
    $this->load->view('view2');
```

that's it.....or you wish to give same view but diff parameters then you keep data for post relatively...you can

```
$data['general'] = 'Main';
if($_POST)
    $data['for post'] = 'something';
$this->load->view('comman_view',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the $_POST variable you need to check to a variable and pass it to the view. You can then remove the loaded view from the DOM using jQuery after the view has been rendered after checking the passed variable's value on the view. The downside of using this is the redundant process of rendering the view and removing it again.

```
$("#the-id-of-the-added-view").remove();
```

But as @sergey-telshevsky suggested though, you should be able to change the logic as to not do the unload in the first place.